# React ref to component not exposing method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using a ref to component to imperatively trigger a reset on a filter form from its parent.

In the same component we have:

```
handleFilterReset() {
  // this.filterForm is defined but reset() isn't exposed
  // see console.log(this.filterForm) output below
  this.filterForm.reset()
}

render() {
  return (
    <FilterBox onReset={::this.handleFilterReset}>
      <FilterForm ref={(ref) => { this.filterForm = ref }} />
    </FilterBox>
  )
}
```

And in FilterForm we have:

```
class FilterForm extends React.Component {
  reset() {
    // this is not being called
  }
}
```

console.log output:

> ProxyComponent {props: Object, context: Object, refs: Object, updater: Object, _reactInternalInstance: ReactCompositeComponentWrapper…}

It seems to me that everything is done according to the [official docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html). However, I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.filterForm.reset is not a function
>
> at SalesChannelsList.handleFilterReset

Thanks

Comment: Very basic suggestion Thibaut, could be a React version thing, but as per the docs provided it should be `class FilterForm extends React.Component` - you're missing `React.`.

Comment: @Gorbles, maybe he would have forgotten to write it in the post, but if you import like `import React, {Component} from 'react'`, you can do that

Comment: You are making use of `::` for binding, can you try to use `handleFilterReset = () => {` and call like `<FilterBox onReset={this.handleFilterReset}>`

Comment: @Gorbles Indeed I use import React, { Component } from 'react'. I tried to keep the code as simple as possible in the example the filter out the noise, but I'll edit the question so it will clarify things :)

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri tried it and still doesn't work. The handleFilterReset() is being called so the problem doesn't lie here I think...

Comment: I understand that it is not recommended, but can you try the same with string refs and see if it works. Can you post some more code for the FilterForm component

Comment: Share the complete example code if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it ! It was "because" of React Intl.

1) Use the withRef option set to true when using injectIntl:

```
injectIntl(SalesChannelsFilterForm, { withRef: true })
```

2) In the ref callback of your component, you can access your instance with the following code

```
ref={(ref) => this.filterForm = ref.refs.wrappedInstance}
```

However this will crash because the ref callback is being called twice during the render(), the 1st time with a null value. So you should 1st verify that it has been defined. My complete solution:

In the render() method, on the component:

```
ref={::this.setFilterFormRef}
```

Then the handler:

```
setFilterFormRef(ref) {
  if (ref && ref.refs) {
    this.filterForm = ref.refs.wrappedInstance
  }
}
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

I would use ref="refName" instead of having a function (which is created again every render) and then access it through `this.refs`.

Anyway, here is a working example:

https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KjHtMcw3LcVEycggzWU

Comment: Thx @jony89. This was my initial solution, which doesn't work neither. BTW working with string refs is now deprecated (see official doc: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

Comment: So please provide your  full code, cause it should work.

Comment: Ok with further debugging, I could obtain the following insight : the ref isn't a regular component instance, but a ProxyComponent (just as indicated in the console.log of the initial question). It is because the component that is being ref'ed is actually obtained from a base class : getFilterForm() { return SalesChannelsFilterForm }. However, I coulnd't find a viable solution, even when using return <SalesChannelFilterForm ref=... />.